# how can i prevent index modification in Stack ( array implementation ) in Java only

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, stack, private

I create Stack using array where there is attribute **private int index = 0**;
In main function when i type **st.index = 8**; and System.out.println(st.size); then **output is 8**, where "st" is an object of Stack class.

I don't want that anybody change this **index**. to prevent this problem I made this variable private. Still it is changeable.

```
public class Stack_04 {

    public static class StackArray {
        private int[] arr = new int[5];
        private static int index = 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackArray st = new StackArray();
        st.index = 8;
        System.out.println(st.index);
    }
}
```

Comment: *there is attribute private int index = 0;* There's nothing called 'index' in that code

Comment: Get rid of `static` and put that class in its own java file

Comment: you should use private static final instead to make it constant.

Comment: @WingKuiTsoi what would be the use of an index variable that's `final`?

Comment: If you mean index is not a constant value, then you may protect it from the class access level (not everyone can access the class).